# tikz: how to change numbers to letters (x-axis) in this code?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I label all subgrids in x with letters instead of numbers? I tried this, but the last four sub grids are not labelled at all:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=30pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}  

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{test.jpg}};

     \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]        

        \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1,thick,yellow] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        \foreach \y in {1,...,10} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10-.05) {\y}; }
        \begin{axis}[xticklabels={,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J},yticklabels={}]
        \end{axis}


     \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=30pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image}};

     \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]        
        \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1,thick,yellow] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        \foreach \y in {1,...,10} 
            \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10-.05) {\y}; 
        \foreach \x [count=\nx] in  {A,B,...,J} 
            \node [anchor=north] at (\nx/10-.05,0) {\x}; 
     \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]